# Trying to use Replace to change the output of value on a view using custom text

Tags: views

I'm trying to figure out how I can replace `underscores` and a specific text using `Replace` on a Drupal 8 view custom text. In a template, I could use the following code to replace specific text.

```
<span class="tag">{{ items.entity.getType|replace({'_': " ", "2": ""}) }}</span>
```

what can I use on a view on custom text? I tried using `{{ type|replace({'_': " ", "2": ""}) }}` but it seems to show the text as plain text, not HTML markup.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Quick and dirty fix for this type of output is pipe it to `raw`. So something like: `{{ type|replace({'_': " ", "2": ""})|raw }}`

Comment: The better fix is to do this in a preprocessor, and add it to an `'#markup'` render array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple string replacement in views output?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251317/simple-string-replacement-in-views-output)

Answer (score 1):

have you try to use *Rewrite results* in views field settings? In *Rewrite results* there is an option *Override the output of this field with custom text* if you click on it it will let you change the output of this field to whatever you want.
plus there will be a *Replacement patterns* option which will show you a list of replacement tokens. also you can add some HTML if you want/need to.

Comment: This doesn't allow you to replace a character with another.